# Is it possible for a supervisor to transfer a chat from one agent to a different one using Omni-Channel?

Tags: omnichannel, chat, omni-supervisor

The use case is, there are two users logged in, Jane and Joe. Joe steps away from his desk and forgets to log out of chat. Omni-Channel routes the chat to Joe and it is auto accepted. Is it possible for Joe and Jane's supervisor to transfer the chat from Joe to Jane?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve this via [Custom Supervisor Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_set_up_custom_actions.htm&type=5) that we added as part of Winter '23.

To do this, you'll need to create a Screen Flow that the Supervisor interacts with and then expose this an action within the appropriate tab. The steps to do these are both in the link I've attached above. One key thing to take into account is the IDs that are passed to the Flow are different based on which Tab the action is exposed on, so you're likely to have to query for the records in the Flow and allow the supervisor to select them as the ID in this instance would only be the Queue IDs.

Comment: Callum MacErlich, what would I have the flow do?